# Pay with a like on iOS & Android

Tags: android, ios, facebook, twitter

How can I allow my iOS & Android user to use premium features if they liked a facebook page or if they twitted a message.

In other word how to implement **Pay With A Tweet** or **Pay With A Like** in mobile apps?

Answer (score 1):

You can either build this functionality natively, using various social media platforms' SDKs (if they offer one) or by redirecting to something like a `UIWebView` and retrieving the success callback to ensure they did what they were supposed to do.

Alternatively, you could use a 3rd party platform such as [TapJoy](https://www.tapjoy.com/homepage) or [ChartBoost](https://www.chartboost.com/) that implements this concept using a pre-built SDK.

Comment: What title I should look for in TapJoy or Chartboost SDKs? Thank you.

Comment: I've never used Chartboost, but TapJoy has a getting started video here: http://developers.tapjoy.com/how-it-works/?lang=en